# Search for any of list of strings in regex

Tags: regex

I'd like to get 6 of 32 files off of an FTP site, but the 3rd-party ETL tool I'm using only lets me use a target directory and a regex filter to get files.

While I could use 6 separate FTP steps and specifically name one file to get, that's sloppy.  Is there a way with regular expressions that I can say give me all files that match an item in this set: {.*XYZInstrument.* , .*XSYFund, etc. }?

For example, match XYZFund.txt/zip and XYZInstrument.txt/zip, but not Index.txt/zip or any other files that happen to be present:

```
SomeName_XYZFund.txt
SomeName_XYZFund.zip
SomeName_XYZIndex.txt
SomeName_XYZIndex.zip
SomeName_XYZInstrument.txt
SomeName_XYZInstrument.zip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use `()` and `|`. For example, to match file.*, *.txt or *.pdf:

`(^file\.|\.txt$|\.pdf$)`

**w00te - Editing Post To Make Definite Answer:**

For my case:  `.*XYZFUND.* | .*XYZINSTRUMENT.*` does the job.

Comment: Thanks, figured it out after you pointed out the pipe operator :)